# How to add some items or some pixmaps to the qgraphicscene?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to make a puzzle game. My thought came from the 8-puzzle problem, so now I try to use the pyqt5. My opinion is that I choose a picture from my computer and then I try to use it. But when I try to upset the picture ,it comes some trouble.So I come here and look for help

since it comes to trouble so I simplify the code that just make the picture change into pieces. And now I just try them list on the qgraphicscene firstly, but I don't known why all of them stacked in the upper left corner, I just want them list in order which looks like the original picture, what should I do?

```py
import sys
from vision import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QFileDialog
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PIL import Image


class MyWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.item = []
        self.if_opened = 0
        self.dim = 3

        self.upset.clicked.connect(self.make_upset)

    def make_upset(self):

        if self.image is None:
            return

        self.scene.clear()
        self.showView.setScene(self.scene)

        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(self.image)
        x_side = self.image_file.size[0] / self.dim
        y_side = self.image_file.size[1] / self.dim

        count = 0
        self.item.clear()
        for j in range(self.dim):
            for i in range(self.dim):
                m = pixmap.copy(i * x_side, j * y_side, x_side, y_side)
                self.item.append(QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem(m))
                self.scene.addItem(self.item[count])
                count = count + 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myShow = MyWindow()
    myShow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1077, 741)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")


        self.upset = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.upset.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(800, 210, 171, 51))
        self.upset.setObjectName("upset")

        self.showView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
        self.showView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(55, 38, 643, 623))
        self.showView.setObjectName("showView")



        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.upset.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "upset"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment ! I try to put all the code here , this is my first time to ask questions here and  you are first man who reply me ヾ(≧▽≦*)o

Comment: @Eric_Seaser read [ask]